# Access "this" inside Fancybox options

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a link to open Fancybox box as follows:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="<?php echo $image_src; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
```

The link has `data` attribute populated with an `id` as above. I want to make the data attribute available inside the Fancybox helper function. I have tried using `$(this.element).data('id')` in the code below:

```
helpers: {
    title: {
        type: 'over'
    },
    buttons: {
        position: 'bottom',
        tpl: '<div id="fancybox-buttons"><ul> \
                                            <li class="button"><a class="test-btn" data-id="' + $(this.element).data('id') + '" href="#"></a></li> \
                                        </ul></div>'
    }
}
```

However it does not work. Fetching the data attribute always returns `undefined` within the helper function. How do I get this working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@meagar presented a great solution that normally would work for most people. However, since the links that were used to call Fancybox were loaded on the page via an Ajax request, his solution did not work for me. I resolved it by declaring a global variable and then passing the value of `$(this.element).data('id')` to the global variable in Fancybox `afterLoad` callback.

```
afterLoad : function() {
    my_global_var = $(this.element).data('id');
}
```

Then I simple used the global variable inside of the helper options.

Comment: Just be careful with your solution. The drawback is that `my_global_var` will be still `undefined` for the first element. Then it will apply the value of `$(this.element).data('id')` of the first element to the second and so on and so forth.

Comment: @JFK That's what I thought initially. However, this works for the first element as well, without any issues.

Comment: hard to believe without seeing it ;)

Comment: @JFK I understand. But here's my reasoning (maybe, I could be wrong). The Helper function runs after the afterLoad callback but before the afterShow callback. So by the time the Helper function runs, the afterLoad callback would have already passed the value to the global variable. If I were to do the same with afterShow callback though, it would behave exactly as you described.

Answer (score 2):

`$(this.element).data('id')` is being evaluated at the time you're binding the callback. `this` will be whatever context you're in at the time you're calling `$.fancybox`.

If you're binding a Fancybox to an anchor tag, you already have selected that anchor tag. Something like this should work:

```
$('a.fancybox').each(funcion () {
  var $a = $(this);
  $a.fancybox({ tpl: "..." + $a.data('id') + "..." });
});
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. Applying the above solution results in the image opening in a new window instead of fancybox. Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably have a JavaScript error somewhere. Install Firebug and debug it.

Comment: I am debugging with Firebug and there are no JS errors. The moment I wrap fancybox function within the `each` function, the image opens in another window instead of fancybox.

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with Ajax loaded content. The `a.fancybox` link is ajax loaded. Any idea on how I could incorporate `each` with `.on` for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be easier to do it with php like?

```
buttons : { 
 position: 'bottom',
 tpl: '...<a class="test-btn" data-id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" href="#"></a>...'
}
```

The issue is that you cannot use `$(this.element)` out of a *callback* function ... you are trying to use it within a template instead.

Comment: — Indeed this could be done in PHP. However that would require me to make the javascript inline of PHP (which I do not intend to do). The Fancybox callback is inside of a separate JS file. I resolved this using a global var. See my answer. Thanks for the inputs.